# How to plot a 3D surface in matlab using set of data

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, surface

I have a set of 3D data which are not ordered. I need to plot a surface which basically connects them together and color the surface based on my z values. 
Here is an example of the data that I have.

-0.144847    -5.239271   -0.000000

-5.430672    -0.044747   0.000000

0.006860    0.282666   -0.000000

0.385219    0.005522   -0.000000

-6.464983    -7.105215   -0.000000

-7.028026    -4.026576   0.000000

-6.092855    -1.826723   -0.000000

-5.619010    -0.886051   0.000000

-5.769190    -0.487232   0.000000

-3.496163    -7.561789   -0.000000

-1.883844    -7.683578   0.000000

-0.845860    -6.159235   -0.000000

-0.487085    -5.865159   0.000000

-5.442694    0.346838   -0.000000

0.158343    -5.402572   -0.000000

0.075667    0.309257   0.000000

0.648079    -1.368195   0.000000

0.510721    -0.525318   0.000000

-0.749283    0.435931   0.000000

-0.338834    0.399974   -0.000000

-0.151157    0.367955   0.000000

-0.071820    0.371475   0.000000

-0.125133    -4.846842   -1.025075

-5.425106    0.058539   -0.341047

0.006806    0.282034   -0.057553

0.384929    0.005456   -0.021184

-5.890619    -6.417012   -0.339540

-6.828500    -3.837339   -0.394468

-6.048110    -1.732177   -0.362965

-5.597372    -0.822289   -0.333655

-5.815376    -0.394711   -0.360211

-3.447449    -7.345610   -0.198281

-1.883239    -7.680056   -0.098589

-0.845817    -6.153723   -0.041199

-0.487017    -5.863854   -0.019289

-5.475775    0.419626   -0.104516

0.159202    -5.400629   -0.017949

0.189255    0.205864   -0.010534

0.280893    0.151170   -0.015441

0.327987    0.090052   -0.018171

0.128256    0.272671   -0.006972

0.075667    0.309256   -0.003940

0.652881    -2.917007   -0.040059

0.647424    -1.368548   -0.037539

0.510386    -0.525737   -0.029055

0.546600    -0.273572   -0.030561

0.448142    -0.108028   -0.024821

-1.643195    0.460307   -0.102182

-0.751135    0.435615   -0.045282

-0.326989    0.388574   -0.019874

-0.151168    0.367766   -0.009394

-0.071815    0.371646   -0.004734

-0.125133    -4.846842   -1.025075

-5.425106    0.058539   -0.341047

0.006806    0.282034   -0.057553

0.384929    0.005456   -0.021184

-5.890619    -6.417012   -0.339540

-6.828500    -3.837339   -0.394468

-6.048110    -1.732177   -0.362965

-5.597372    -0.822289   -0.333655

-5.815376    -0.394711   -0.360211

-3.447449    -7.345610   -0.198281

-1.883239    -7.680056   -0.098589

I have around 400 points, like the ones above.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What format is your data in and what kind of plot do you want? Once you have separated the data into 3 variables it is simple to plot it into a 3-D scatter plot and specify the color using:

scatter3(X,Y,Z,S,C)

More info is available on the mathworks website which is SUPER useful for figuring out MATLAB